# Can clickonce alert me if prerequisites fail to install for user?

Tags: error-handling, clickonce, prerequisites

I am using clickonce to distribute my VB.net windows application. It has several prerequisites, which are automatically installed by clickonce as soon as the user attempts to download the software. (e.g. DotNet Framework 3.5)

I would really like to have some kind of way of being alerted if any prerequisites fail to install- preferably an email sent to my account.

Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Comment: As a personal feeling, I would really not want an application to send emails without my consent.

Comment: Ok. Well maybe give the user an option to send an error report or not then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, ClickOnce is pretty much feature-locked and I fear that you have to look at other products to implement such a feature.

You can have a look a NSIS for example: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page